# NodeJS: Very large JSON from remote resource parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

I have a very large JSON file(150k lines, ~3mb) coming from an external resource,
I wonder what is the best approach to work with it under NodeJS application.

My strategy at the moment was get it with an ajax call, parse it and store it in cache:

```
var options = {
host: url,
port: port,
path: '/file.json',
headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' +password).toString('base64')
    }
};

http.get(options, function (res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        var JsonAsObject = JSON.parse(body);
        StatisticsCache.set("Json", JsonAsObject, function(err, success) {
           console.log("err is " + err + "success is " + success);
        });
    })
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got error: ", e);
});
```

But what I exprience is that this line:

```
var JsonAsObject = JSON.parse(body);
```

Takes forever (3 minutes) and even then the object is not accessible in debug.

In the end my goal is to be able and process it's information,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a streaming parser so you aren’t storing everything in memory at once. It may still take a couple seconds to run, but at least your app won’t stall while it is parsing.

Try [JSONStream](http://npmjs.org/package/JSONStream):

```
var request = require('http').request,
    parseUrl = require('url').parse,
    JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var url = parseUrl('…');
url.method = 'GET';

var req = request(url, function (res) {
  res.pipe(JSONStream.parse()).on('data', function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  });
});
req.end();
```